# How can I use unique_ptr with a more generic deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Consider some function:

```
template<typename F>
void foo(F f) {
  std::unique_ptr<int> p = f();
  // do some stuff with p
}
```

Because `unique_ptr` decrees a default template argument, `default_delete`, for `D`, any function object passed to `foo` that returns a `unique_ptr` with a non-default deleter fails to compile.  For example,

```
int x = 3;
foo([&x](){
    // use empty deleter
    return std::unique_ptr<int>(&x, [](int*){});
});
```

However, I could see this being potentially useful, and I don't see a direct reason why it shouldn't be possible.  Is there a common approach for addressing this?

**Edit**

The easy fix would be to define `foo` instead to use the following:

```
  std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> p = f();
```

But I'm wondering why this couldn't have been incorporated into the interface for `unique_ptr`?  Is there a reason the class interface couldn't provide this generic attribute?  Are there approaches for "wrapping" this kind of thing into a new definition?

For example,

```
template<typename T>
using Generic_unique_ptr =
  std::unique_ptr<
    T,
    std::function< void(typename std::unique_ptr<T>::element_type*) >
  >;
```

But this seems dangerous because it exposes the potential to do something like the follwing,

```
Generic_unique_ptr<int> p(new int());
```

which would leave the deleter uninitialized and exhibit undefined behavior.  Perhaps some way to provide ***an instance of*** `std::default_delete<T>` as the default deleter?

Comment: @TemplateRex I'm not sure they're the same.  How can the deleter type be deduced from template argument `F`?

Comment: The type can be taken using the new `decltype()` function (since C++11). There were some limited ways of doing such in older compilers using templates, but that was really not practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is use the pointer in a function, you can just
use the `auto` keyword; the compiler will deduce the type of `unique_ptr`
which has been used and thus automatically do the right thing:

```
template <typename F>
void foo(F f)
{
    auto p = f();
    p->bar();
}
```

Now, from your comment, we know that this is not all you want, but you
want to be able to store the `unique_ptr` in your class to work with
it later. This creates a set of completely different problems:

1. `unique_ptr<T, D1>` and `unique_ptr<T, D2>` are different types. Thus we need to know what `unique_ptr<T, D>` will be returned by your functor `F`
2. Even if we knew the return type of `F` in advance, our class can still only store `unique_ptr<T, D1>` and not `unique_ptr<T, D2>`.

The easiest way around this (that I can think of, there might be better
ways) is *type erasure*.

We create ourselves a base class that exposes the pointer managed by the
`unique_ptr`:

```
template <typename T>
struct wrapper
{
    virtual ~wrapper() {}
    virtual T const * get() const = 0;
    virtual T * get() = 0;
};
```

From that class inherits our actual storage class, which deduces the type
of `unique_ptr`:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
struct storage
    : wrapper<T>
{
    storage(F f) { p_ = f(); }
    T const * get() const { return p_.get(); }
    T * get() { return p_.get(); }

    private:
        typename std::result_of<F()>::type p_;
};
```

In the class you actually care about, you can now store a pointer to our
base class and use polymorphism to access the underlying object, in this
case the `unique_ptr`. Assume we moved the classes above into 
`namespace detail` to hide them from the user:

```
template <typename T>
class some_class
{
    public:
        template <typename F>
        void store(F f)
        {
            storage_.reset(new detail::storage<T, F>(f));
        }

        T const * get() const { return storage_->get(); }
        T * get() { return storage_->get(); }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<detail::wrapper<T>> storage_;
};
```

You can find a fully working example [here](http://ideone.com/C5WMgj).

Comment: That is fantastic!  I have been guilty of not giving that keyword much attention, but it solves this problem brilliantly!

Comment: That's awesome.  I tried doing something similar and failed miserably.

Answer (score 2):

> But I'm wondering why this couldn't have been incorporated into the interface for unique_ptr?

Because to do so would force all of `std::function`'s overhead onto *everyone*. `unique_ptr` is intended to be useful for pretty much any case of single ownership of a pointer. You pay for what you use; not everyone who uses a custom deleter needs that deleter to be *generic*. This way, they don't have to pay for it.

Also, the current methodology allows it to handle non-pointer resources, as the deleter can specify exactly what type gets stored in the `unique_ptr`.

If you want to provide this generic deleter construct, you could create a class that (privately) inherits from `unique_ptr` and replicates its interface, minus the constructor that doesn't take a deleter instance. That way, the user is forced to pass a deleter function in.

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer.  I'll look into this.

Comment: +1 for why, -1 for saying someone should inherit from `std::unique_ptr`: why inherit from a type in `std`, when a member variable does just as well?

Comment: @Yakk: Because it isn't "just as well". It's much easier to export an interface from an inherited class than a member class.

Comment: @NicolBolas other than inherited constructors, how exactly?  And in this case, a simple single argument perfect forwarding constructor is only marginally more bulky than using an inherited constructor.

Comment: @Yakk: Because you can use `using` syntax to forward more than just constructors. There's more to `unique_ptr`'s interface than just the constructor.